# MAAS 1.9 can't deploy OS

Tags: maas

I recently upgraded my MAAS server and found myself with MAAS 1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1. I saw that the old version of MAAS that I had been running was no longer supported, so no great loss there.

Unfortunately, every time I try and deploy Trusty to a node, it fails with the console message "DataSourceNotFoundException: Did not find any data source, searched classes: ()" on the node and the MAAS server eventually times out the deployment.

My system configuration is both very simple, and probably quite different from a common MAAS installation. In particular, I am not using the optional DNS and DHCP modules because I already have a perfectly good DNS and DHCP system. This worked great in 1.8, but I guess something has gone wrong in the new fancy network framework.

I can reproduce this easily with the following steps:

1. `apt-get install maas`
2. `maas-region-admin createadmin ...`
3. Power on the node to enlist it - that works
4. Commission the node - that works
5. Deploy Trusty to the node - that doesn't
6. Scratch head when the deployment fails

My MAAS server is 10.0.1.51/24, the nodes I am deploying are on 10.76.0.0/23, and I have a DHCP server that directs the PXE boot to fetch the PXE boot files from the MAAS server.

This all used to work fine with 1.8. Does anyone have any ideas about what might need to be poked or prodded to allow deployments to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best way to figure out what is failing is to SSH to a node while it being commissioned and to check /var/log directory. There is a log for a cloud-init script. If that part did complete correctly then look for /var/log/juju and the logs inside it will give a you a clue on what might be failing.

Answer (score -1):

You may expect quick and perfect answers if you post an issue in https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer

Comment: I would count this more as a comment, rather than an answer to the problem.